# Getting access token with App secret. Is it safe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Im building an app that tries to display the last 5 news of certain public page. To access this information I need to get an access token with this:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &grant_type=client_credentials
```

My question is: isn't the app secret to be... well, secret?

If I make a GET query mit jQuery anyone can look into the script file and find out about it. Is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token never changes (unless password change / block / ...). 
You should retrieve the token once using your browser. From then on you can use the token without using your app secret.

Comment: Well, thats what I did yesterday, and today the token wasn't working anymore. Maybe am I missing some setting in the Facebook Developer page?